# How stop the pause “um…” in Bark

Tags: audio

I am generating audio by using bark

I dun want to have anymore pause like “um… ar…”

How can i do

```
from bark.generation import (
    generate_text_semantic,
    preload_models,
)
from bark.api import semantic_to_waveform
from bark import generate_audio, SAMPLE_RATE
preload_models()
script = """
```

Comment: Is it about silence = np.zeros(int(0.25 * SAMPLE_RATE))  # quarter second of silence